# Beautifulsoup not returning complete HTML of the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been digging on the site for some time and im unable to find the solution to my issue.   Im fairly new to web scraping and trying to simply extract some links from a web page using beautiful soup.

```
url = "https://www.sofascore.com/pt/futebol/2018-09-18"
page = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

At the most basic level, all im trying to do is access a specific tag within the website.   I can work out the rest for myself, but the part im struggling with is the fact that a tag that I am looking for is not in the output.

For example:  using the built in find() I can grab the following div class tag: 
    class="l__grid js-page-layout"

However what i'm actually looking for are the contents of a tag that is embedded at a lower level in the tree.
    js-event-list-tournament-events

When I perform the same find operation on the lower-level tag, I get no results.

Using Azure-based Jupyter Notebook,  i have tried a number of the solutions to similar problems on stackoverflow and no luck.

Thanks! 
Kenny

Comment: That website is using a lot of javascript, so you have to use something like [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Hi Kenny, you could follow this tutorial https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The page use JS to load the data dynamically so you have to use selenium. Check below code.
Note you have to install selenium and [chromedrive](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/) (unzip the file and copy into python folder)

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/pt/futebol/2018-09-18"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={
    'class':'js-event-list-tournament-events'})
print(container)
```

or you can use their json api

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.sofascore.com/football//2018-09-18/json'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the following code worked for me. Chromedriver must be installed!

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path= "/Users/.../chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
url = "https://yourURL.com"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3) #if you want to wait 3 seconds for the page to load
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
```

This `soup` you can use as usual.