# Selenium cannot find element even after giving a high implicitly waiting time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, automation

Im trying to automize some webpages and run into the following error:
I have passed the login screen, which gives no problems, but after being redirected to the next page, python gives the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I have tried to fix it by introducing the `driver.implicitly.wait`, the `time.sleep` and the  `WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))` functions, but all the options do not seem to work.

I have shown the relevant HTML code below:

```
<input type="Text" class="urEdf2TxtEnbl" autocomplete="off" id="DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp" ct="I" name="DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp" st="" tp="STRING" value="502309" onchange="sapUrMapi_InputField_change('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onblur="sapUrMapi_InputField_Blur('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_InputField_keydown('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onkeyup="sapUrMapi_InputField_KeyUp('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onfocus="sapUrMapi_InputField_focus('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onselectstart="sapUrMapi_InputField_onselectstart('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_5_VARINPUT_inp',event);">
```

The HTML code in the region around this is shown below:

```
<input type="Text" class="urEdf2TxtEnbl" autocomplete="off" id="DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp" ct="I" name="DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp" st="" tp="STRING" value="" onchange="sapUrMapi_InputField_change('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onblur="sapUrMapi_InputField_Blur('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_InputField_keydown('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onkeyup="sapUrMapi_InputField_KeyUp('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onfocus="sapUrMapi_InputField_focus('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);" onselectstart="sapUrMapi_InputField_onselectstart('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_4_VARINPUT_inp',event);">
```

What I am trying to do is to change the value: `value="502309"`. See below for the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('xxxx')
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')
login.send_keys('xxx')
passw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')
passw.send_keys('xxx')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxx')
button.click()
driver.maximize_window()  

driver.implicitly_wait(120)

mat = driver.find_element_by_id('DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR_2_VARINPUT_inp')




driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the html using beautifulsoup so you can check if the element really exist. For your reference on how to use it, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page)

Comment: It does exist, you can see it in the inspection page of the browser

Comment: There are times that when you manually visit the site and inspect it, the element is present. However during the automation execution, it might be not. Other thing you may try is to put pause or sleep and inspect the site while on the execution. Let me know if you can find the element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but i had the same problem and solved it by this:

```
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "your_xpath_here")
```

The above code shows that the webdriver will wait's for an element located in your page.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work, I get the following error due to the timeoutexception of this function:


  File, line 19, in <module>
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id=""]"')))
  File "", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is not wait , but rather correct element locator. As far as I can see from limited HTML DOM you have provided, part of name and id of element you want to locate inside variable **mat** is changing. You can locate your element using below code ( Also i have included more sophisticated way to wait for element load).

```
mat = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@id,'DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_CommonVariablesList_VAR')]")))
```