# Finding tables returns [] with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from this url: https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply
I gather that the table I want is in the div class "dataTables_scroll". I use the following code and it only returns an empty list:

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get("https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply")
soup = bs(url.content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "dataTables_scroll"})

print(table)
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is because the website uses javascript. Use `selenium` with `chromedriver`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page

Comment: This site seems to be using JS to generate content. You cannot use BS4 for that and @J.Choi hinted, need to use selenium with chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the response you get from requests.get() does not contain table data in it.

It might be loaded on client-side(by javascript).

What can you do about this? Using a selenium webdriver is a possible solution. You can "wait" until the table is loaded and becomes interactive, then get the page content with selenium, pass the context to bs4 to do the scraping.

You can check the response by writing it to a file:

```
f = open("demofile.html", "w", encoding='utf-8')
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

and you will be able to see "...Loading..." where the table is expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page from the first comment and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the data is loaded from a script tag. I have to go to work so can't spend more time working out how to appropriately recreate the a dataframe from the "|" delimited data at present, but the following may serve as a starting point for others, as it extracts the relevant entries from the script tag for the table body.

```
import requests, re
import ast

r = requests.get('https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply').text
s = re.search(r'cl\.coinmainlist\.dataraw = (\[.*?\]);', r, flags = re.S).group(1)
data = ast.literal_eval(s)
data = [i.split('|') for i in data]
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page from the first comment and it worked for me!