# Python Web scraping Hidden jpg images that I can't figure out how to download from this internet site

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Hi I've been trying all day to find a way to download some images from this
URL: https://omgcheckitout.com/these-trypophobia-photos-will
but when I run this code I always get only the URLs for the small images in the corner and not the ones found in the article.
(I've also tried other ways but I get always the same result)

'''

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://omgcheckitout.com/these-trypophobia-photos-will'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
images = soup.find_all('img')

for image in images:
    print(images['src'])
```

'''

Comment: I believe what is happening here is that the page that you are seeing in the browser is being loaded dynamically with javascript. Try typing in '.html' to the page url and see what happens. The images in the redirect are what are being downloaded with your code. I recommend taking a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page

Comment: Thank you, it seems that now I can find the desired Url's

Comment: Wonderful! I am going to convert my comment to an answer so that the question can be marked as 'solved'.
Don't forget to click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and will help to indicate that the question has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Converting my comment to an answer

original comment:

"I believe what is happening here is that the page that you are seeing in the browser is being loaded dynamically with javascript. Try typing in '.html' to the page url and see what happens. The images in the redirect are what are being downloaded with your code. I recommend taking a look at this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687372/beautifulsoup-not-returning-complete-html-of-the-page%22)

Answer (score 0):

Try to download them to your disk

import requests
from os.path  import basename

```
r = requests.get("xxx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for link in links:
    if "http" in link.get('src'):
        lnk = link.get('src')
        with open(basename(lnk), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(lnk).content)

    for image in images:
        print(images['src'])
```

You can also use a select to filter your tags to only get the ones with http links:

```
for link in soup.select("img[src^=http]"):
        lnk = link["src"]
        with open(basename(lnk)," wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(lnk).content)
```